# How do you call an action when a teacher makes final marks?

Tags: phrase-request

An action when a teacher in a high school makes final marks for students.

How is this action called in Standard English?

I came up with a few phrases, but have no idea if any of them is correct.

- finalizing marks
- finalizing grades
- concluding marks/grades

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "final marks". For example, final marks on an assignment or the final grade when the course is completed. You should add some additional description and an example would be helpful.

Comment: It's the final mark at the end of a course.

Comment: Then I would say "final grade(s)". But this probably varies with locale.

Comment: What would the verb be? Finalizing?

Comment: A teacher can *calculate* each student's final grade before posting them or turning them in, or whatever protocol he or she uses.

Answer (score 2):

Grades are ordinarily *awarded* by the teacher and *reported* or *posted* to whatever system, manual or digital, the institution uses for recording grades. My wife posts grades in the course she teaches to an online system.

I can think of no verb specific to the action of awarding final marks or grades in a course; what changes in this case is the verb's direct object, not the verb itself.

In my day (60s and 70s) many teachers also "posted", literally, a list of final grades on a bulletin board or on their office doors, but I don't think that is done much any more—nobody hangs around between semesters to consult such a list. In those days  grades were mailed to students by the university during the break between semesters, but in the courses she takes my wife now learns her final grades at her online account.

Comment: My wife just *turned in* her grades (which harkens to an earlier day when they weren't *submitted* online).

Comment: @Jim True. And once upon a time we asked if Prof. So-and-so had *put up* his grades yet.